# Unable to convert List of Tuples [('1',), ('2',), ('3',)] into List ['1', '2', '3']?

Tags: python, list, sqlite, tuples

A complicated tuple generated by sqlite3.
Like this:

```
[('1', '2', '3')]
```

How can I convert a tuple into a list like with this output:

```
[('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]
```

to

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

?

list(arr) does not work, sum(list(arr), []) does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
a = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]

[''.join(i) for i in a]
```

Comment: Thanks. Accepting in 8 minuets

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list() to convert tuple to list and appending the result in an array.

```
arr1 = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]
arr2 = []
for ele in arr1:
    arr2 = arr2+list(ele)

print(arr2) //['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extend method of list

```
l1=[('1',), ('2',), ('3',)]
result=[]
for data in l1:
    result.extend(data)
print(result)
```